JavaFX: How to cause change events when changing members of an ObjectProperty
I have a class MyObject and a class MyOtherObject (To keep the post as short as possible, I'll leave out the getter and setter here and just use the members directly.):
public class MyObject
{
    public StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    public ObjectProperty<MyOtherObject> myOtherObject = new SimpleObjectProperty<MyOtherObject>();
    
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + (myOtherObject.get() == null ? "?" : myOtherObject.get().text );
    }
    
    public static Callback<MyObject, Observable[]> extractor()
    {
        return (myObject) ->
        {
            return new Observable[] { myObject.name, myObject.myOtherObject };
        };
    }
}


public class MyOtherObject
{
    public StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty("");
}

Objects of the MyObject class are displayed in a ListView:
ListView<MyObject> myListView = new ListView<MyObject>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(MyObject.extractor()));

So that the ListView updates correctly when an item changes, I pass the extractor with the properties that can change to the FXCollections.observableArrayList call.
Basically, this works as intended. The following manipulations are recognized correctly and the ListView updates the text of the items.
MyObject myObject = myListView.getItems( XXX );
myObject.name.set("XYZ");

MyOtherObject myOtherObject = XXX;
myObject.myOtherObject.set(myOtherObject);

However, manipulations of the MyOtherObject itself are not recognized. The following manipulation is not recognized and the ListView does not update the text of the items.
MyObject myObject = myListView.getItems( XXX );
myObject.myOtherObject.get().text.set("XYZ");

This is of course due to the fact that the ObjectProperty myOtherObject member of the MyObject class is not informed when the StringProperty text member of the MyOtherObject class is changed.
How can I solve the problem of ensuring that the items in a ListView are always updated correctly? I would like to find a clean solution and ensure that the ListView is correctly informed about changes to an item. I am not looking for a simple but messy solution, such as removing and adding an item just to inform the ListView of a change.

Try new Observable[] { myObject.name, myObject.myOtherObject, myObject.myOtherObject.flatMap(myOtherObject -> myOtherObject.text)} in the extractor (requires JavaFX 19 or later). You can probably omit myObject.myOtherObject: I haven't tested as there is no [mre].

Yes!  ObservableValue.flatMap()!!!  Note, though, that this is only since JFX 19.  So it won't work in an earlier version.
